How do I compare a specific element of a list to an integer?
I'm currently in the process of developing a tennis-counting system for fun. Since I'm a newby in Python, I'm currently struggling with some parts of the code.
I'm trying to compare the amounts of sets that a player (or both) played to the total amount of sets you can play.
Here's part of my code:
def set():
    global listenpunkteone
    global listenpunktetwo
    global setlisteone
    global setcounter
    global scoreone 
    global scoretwo 
    if setlisteone[setcounter] < 6 and setlistetwo[setcounter] < 6:
        if scoreone == 50:
            scoreone = 0
            listenpunkteone += 1
            setlisteone[setcounter] = listenpunkteone
            print("The score is",setlisteone[setcounter],":", setlistetwo[setcounter])
            game()
        elif scoretwo == 50:
            scoretwo = 0
            listenpunktetwo += 1
            setlistetwo[setcounter] = listenpunktetwo
            print("The score is",setlisteone[setcounter],":", setlistetwo[setcounter])
            game()
    elif setlistetwo[setcounter] == 6:
        setlistetwo[setcounter] = listenpunktetwo
        print("The score is",setlisteone[setcounter],":", setlistetwo[setcounter])
        listenpunktetwo = 0
        setcounter += 1
        setlistetwo[setcounter] = setlistetwo.append(listenpunktetwo) 
        game() 
    elif setlisteone[setcounter] == 6:
        setlisteone[setcounter] = listenpunkteone
        print("The score is",setlisteone[setcounter],":", setlistetwo[setcounter])
        listenpunkteone = 0
        setcounter += 1
        setlisteone[setcounter] = setlisteone.append(listenpunkteone)
        game()

setcounter is supposed to go up by 1 any time that a set has been played (surpassing of 40 points) - it does so nicely up until the score is e.g. 6:0. After, the code just breaks and gives me the Error:
TypeError: '\<' not supported between instances of 'NoneType' and 'int'

Is there any other way for me to compare the specific value of a list element to an integer of my choosing?
Also, I don't understand why my code runs smoothly up until hitting 6:0 -> Shouldn't a new element be automatically appended after reaching 6 and the process repeated?

Don't use set() as your function name, there's a built-in type with the same name.

How do you create setlistone and setlisttwo? The error indicates that it contains None values, and you can't compare None to 6.

You should probably fill it with 0 rather than None.

If you want to count the number of sets they've played, it should probably be if setcounter < 6:

how can each player play a different number of sets? Aren't they playing all the sets against each other?

You should definitely consider using snake_case (preferred) or camelCase for variable names. It's super hard to read otherwise.

If one of the scores reaches 50, then BOTH scores should be reset to zero.  You should probably have one function to handle points, then another function to handle the set, then another function to handle the match.  What you have is confusing too many concepts.   And remember that you have to win a set by two games.  In a 6:5 match, they'll keep playing.

Your question is very specific, I don't know why so much of your code is required to explain it though.

This line:
setlisteone[setcounter] = setlisteone.append(listenpunkteone)

assigns None to setlisteone[setcounter]. This is because append modifies its target in place and returns None. That is the reason you have None in your setlisteXY and therefore your <6 comparison will fail with a TypeError. I have not checked if that is the only problem in your code.
Returning None from functions that modify mutable objects is a python convention, explained in this QA: Why do these list methods (append, sort, extend, remove, clear, reverse) return None rather than the resulting list?
